# How can I group columns around another column (with is dynamic) in a dataframe in python?

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe of products which looks like this

| id_product | code_variant | stock_variant |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3705001874319307 | 1.5 | 6 |
| 3705001874319307 | 1.6 | 8 |
| 2645008795365406 | 1.7 | 7 |
| 2645008795365406 | 1.8 | 7 |

So what I want to is to group all the variant codes and stock around the same `id_product` like this

| id_product | code_variant | stock_variant | code_variant2 | stock_variant2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3705001874319307 | 1.5 | 6 | 1.6 | 8 |
| 2645008795365406 | 1.7 | 7 | 1.8 | 7 |

But it has to be automated, because I have hundred of products and variants, do you have any idea of how to do it?

Comment: Could you provide the code that you have worked on so far?

Comment: I have only load the df from an excel, because I don´t know how to start with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use:

```
df.grouby(['id_product']).groups
```

An example of that would be:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Animal': ['Falcon', 'Falcon',
                              'Parrot', 'Parrot'],
                   'Max Speed': [380., 370., 24., 26.]})
grouped = df.groupby(['Animal']).groups
print(grouped)
```

Output:

```
{'Falcon': [0, 1], 'Parrot': [2, 3]}
```

This would be a better approach than making a column for each new variable and stock. It would save you time and space.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below for grouping the variants by using groupby in Python.

```
df_grouped = df.groupby(['id_product'])

for key, item in df_grouped:
    print(df_grouped. get_group(key))
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cjCer.png) -